# swift UITapGestureRecognizer transfer doubleTap for another view

Tags: swift, maps, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my ViewController i have mapView - maps. In map, if user double tap, map zoom in.
It is default option, i did not set it up.
I add UITapGestureRecognizer, because i work with single tap. But when i double tap, work twice single tap.
I don't want write method for double tap, because mapView understand it.
I think that UITapGestureRecognizer must work with single tap, and don't work when double tap.
My code:

```
let tapTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getObjectProperties))
tapTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapTap.delegate = self
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapTap)
```

How i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the [require(toFail:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require) method. like this `uiTapGestureRecognizer1.require(toFail:uiTapGestureRecognizer2)`

here is the command in context

```
//DOUBLE TAP
uiTapGestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(myDoubleTapGesture(_:)) )
uiTapGestureRecognizer2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
uiTapGestureRecognizer2.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(uiTapGestureRecognizer2)

//SINGLE TAP
uiTapGestureRecognizer1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(mySingleTapGesture(_:)) )
uiTapGestureRecognizer1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
uiTapGestureRecognizer1.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(uiTapGestureRecognizer1)

//so the *first* tap of a double doesn't trigger a single
uiTapGestureRecognizer1.require(toFail:uiTapGestureRecognizer2) //<-- this is the line you need
```